# Invocable apex REST POST

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, future, invocable-method

I'm an admin who pretends to be a developer every once in awhile. I'm trying to use a Flow to initiate a REST POST callout. From other research, I understand this may need to be done with a future method. I'm also trying to use a LeadId from the Flow as an input variable for the apex to populate field values for the callout.

My current error is line 18 `public static HttpResponse makePostCallout() {`
I'm getting a `Missing " at 'public'` error.

```
public class IMGapiInvocable {
    
    public class FlowInputs{
        @InvocableVariable public String LeadId;
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod (label = 'Call Sales Cloud' description='Sends Lead Id to IMG')
    public static void IMGapi(List<Id> Lead)
    {
        IMGapiFuture(Lead);
    }
    
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void IMGapiFuture(List<Id> Lead){
        
    }
}
public static HttpResponse makePostCallout() {
    Lead l = [select FirstName, LastName, Email from Lead where Id = LeadId];

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://myendpoint.com');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setBody('{ "affiliateId":"12345", "FirstName":"' + leadfirstname + '","LastName":"' + leadlastname + '","Email":"' + leademail + '"}');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // Parse the JSON response
    if(response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Love your first sentence. What exactly are you asking? Are you getting an error? Are you getting unexpected results? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/369039/edit) your question to add more info.

Comment: Thanks. I added this: My current error is line 18 public static HttpResponse makePostCallout() { I'm getting a Missing " at 'public' error.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra closing curly brace `}` at line 17, which prematurely closes your class; therefore your `makePostCallout()` method is outside of your class.

Try removing that curly brace.